# Show that $\Pr(S_N\in A\mid N=n)=\Pr(S_n\in A)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

> Let $X_1,.\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables and $N$ be a positive integer-valued random variable, which is independent from the sequence. If $S_n=\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} X_i$, then for a borel set $A$ show that ;$$\Pr(S_N\in A\mid N=n)=\Pr(S_n\in A)$$

If I write

$$\Pr(S_N\in A\mid N=n)=\frac{\Pr(S_N\in A\cap N=n)}{\Pr(N=n)}=\frac{\Pr(S_N\in A)\Pr(N=n)}{\Pr(N=n)}=\Pr(S_N\in A)$$

($2^{nd}$ equality by independence), so where is the mistake ?

but I can also write

$$\Pr(S_N\in A\mid N=n)=\frac{E(\mathbf1_{\{S_N\in A\cap N=n\}})}{\Pr(N=n)}=\frac{E(\mathbf1_{\{S_N\in A\}}\mathbf1_{\{N=n\}})}{\Pr(N=n)}$$

and since

$$\mathbf1_{\{S_N\in A\}}\mathbf1_{\{N=n\}}=\mathbf1_{\{S_n\in A\}}\stackrel{?}\ge\mathbf1_{\{S_n\in A\}}\mathbf1_{\{N=n\}}$$

but if I assume that the inequality above is an equality then it works, I think

$$\frac{E(\mathbf1_{\{S_N\in A\}}\mathbf1_{\{N=n\}})}{\Pr(N=n)}=\frac{E(\mathbf1_{\{S_n\in A\}}\mathbf1_{\{N=n\}})}{\Pr(N=n)}=\frac{\Pr(S_n\in A)\Pr(N=n)}{\Pr(N=n)}=\Pr(S_n\in A)$$

Can you verify this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is that, even if $(S_n)$ and $N$ are independent, 
$S_N$ and $N$ are not.

But you can write 
$$\displaystyle\Pr(S_N\in A|N=n)=
\frac{\Pr(S_N\in A\cap N=n)}{\Pr(N=n)}=
\frac{\Pr(S_n\in A\cap N=n)}{\Pr(N=n)}=
\frac{\Pr(S_n\in A)\Pr(N=n)}{\Pr(N=n)}=
\Pr(S_n\in A)$$because on $\{N=n\}, S_N = S_n$
.

Comment: In your example, $S_N\equiv 1$ is a constant random variable which is independent of $N$.

Comment: yes, thanks. I'll think of something else.

Comment: @mookid Is your proof wrong now ?

Comment: my proof is not.